# Combination of pyinstaller, multiprocessing and QT5 leads to new GUI Windows and crash

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, python-multiprocessing

I had a python QT5 project that was running just fine, except for a few cases where a function was running a long time just to return false in most cases. It doesn't really matter to me if that function is skipped eventually because my programm is running a heuristic anyways and I can afford to lose those edge cases.

The programm is made into an executable with pyinstaller and was running fine then too. The following problem **only** appears in the executable version, not when running in spyder. Logging doesn't reveal any errors so apparently there is no exception.

I'm using this code snippet for time-out:

```
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        return_dict = manager.dict()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_function, args=(a,Pakete,return_dict))
        p.start()
        p.join(10) #timeout after 10 seconds
        if p.is_alive():
            p.terminate()
            p.join()
```

Running the executable, with settings that would normally finish the programm in under a minute and definitly not stay at the timeout section for more than 10 seconds (so no timeout should happen) yiels weird behaviour.

I start the calculations in the GUI, the GUI freezes and opens another GUI. The new GUI is fully functional and yiels the same error.

I do not have a global try-catch-restart, so that can't be it.

I can't provide a working example because I'm at a complete loss how to even reproduce this in small scale.

Is there any known problem with multiprocessing and pyqt and pyinstaller? Any workaround that could work? Any ideas where I could start looking for the problem? In my opinion, this behaviour shoudn't even be possible so there must be some dependency/behaviour hidden deep inside any of these packages.

Comment: Probably this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066043/9059420).

Comment: @Darkonaut I found that solution somewhere where it said it's only needed when creating a --onefile executable, which I'm not. I'll try it tomoroww anyways, but I'm not getting a RuntimeError neither.

Comment: @Darkonaut nevermind, that was actually the problem, I misunderstood the reference I read about that. Thanks a lot!