# Pyinstaller, Multiprocessing, and Pandas - No such file/directory

Tags: pandas, pyinstaller, python-multiprocessing, python-3.9

Program works fine when running in PyCharm.  I tried using PyInstaller for first time to create an .exe file.

My logic is as follows:

1. Read CSV into Dataframe using Pandas
2. Split into 12 Dataframes of roughly equal size
   3  Start 12 threads to process the data and upload to MongoDB

Sample code further below, but here is the error I'm getting.
One thing that blows my mind is that the initial "Start DateTime ..." message appears twice.

```
Start DateTime=2020-11-18 11:29:22
Pandas reading large CSV file
Number of rows in CSV loaded into memory: 12,632,654
group_size= 1,052,721
remainder_size= 2
Number of split_dataframes= 12
Revised Number of split_dataframes= 13
split_df: 0  size= 1052721
split_df: 1  size= 1052721
split_df: 2  size= 1052721
split_df: 3  size= 1052721
split_df: 4  size= 1052721
split_df: 5  size= 1052721
split_df: 6  size= 1052721
split_df: 7  size= 1052721
split_df: 8  size= 1052721
split_df: 9  size= 1052721
split_df: 10  size= 1052721
split_df: 11  size= 1052721
split_df: 12  size= 2
Number of Concurrent Process= 12
Defining Process: 0
Starting Process: 0
Start DateTime=2020-11-18 11:29:41
Pandas reading large CSV file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UploadIP2LocationsToMongoDBMultiProc.py", line 243, in <module>
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
  File "pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2010, in __init__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'parent_pid=22208'
[22956] Failed to execute script UploadIP2LocationsToMongoDBMultiProc
```

The error line 243 points to this line, but it ran okay the first time, and should not be running a second time.

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_filename, dtype=dataTypes)
```

Partial code:

````
```
    print("Start DateTime=" + str(startDateNowFmt))
    
    print("Pandas reading large CSV file")
    df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_filename, dtype=dataTypes)
    print(f"Number of rows in CSV loaded into memory: {len(df.index):,}")
    
    
    print("Number of Concurrent Process=", num_current_processes_to_use)
    processes = []  # hold our processes
    
    for index, split_df in enumerate(df_split_list):
        print("Defining Process:", index)
        process = mp.Process(target=load_dataframe_to_mongodb,
                             args=(index, split_df, arg_mongodb_collection_name)
                             )
        processes.append(process)
        print("Starting Process:", index)
        process.start()
    
    for indx, process in enumerate(processes):
        print("Joining process:", index)
        process.join()
```
````

Comment: I would check the output of the pyInstaller build, use --debug option for aditional information.

Comment: Are you using [multiprocessing.freeze_support()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support)?

Comment: @Darkonaut - adding that line fixed it, amazing! Thanks.  Put in answer instead of comment and I will vote/accept.

Comment: You're welcome. I've answered this already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54065079/9059420), so we should mark it as duplicate instead.

Comment: Darkonaut - Yes, I just would have never found it searching for keywords in that article.  Originally, I thought the issue was with Pandas since pandas\io\parsers.py was in most of the errors.  It was only when I pasting question here, that I saw the program started multiple times.  Thanks